# Hide/Show Form Field (Row) Based on Group

Tags: sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-designer

I am trying to see if within the new/edit form, I can restrict what certain people see based on what user/membership group they are in? I have read that you can use XSLT and achieve something similar by using: `<xsl:if test="ddwrt:IfHasRights(#)"></xsl:if>`. The issue is that we have multiple groups that may have similar privileges, but want to restrict to only a certain number of those groups.

Mainly, I am trying to see if there was a way to write something similar to: `<xsl:if test="ddwrt:GroupName('My Group Name')"></xsl:if>` OR `<xsl:if test="GroupName = 'My Group Name'"></xsl:if>`?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.SPServices/2014.02/jquery.SPServices-2014.02.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
     $().SPServices({
      operation: "GetGroupCollectionFromUser",
      userLoginName: $().SPServices.SPGetCurrentUser(),
      async: false,
      webURL:"http://sp/",
      completefunc: function(xData, Status) {
        console.log(xData.responseXML);
        if ($(xData.responseXML).find("Group[Name='Designers']").length == 1)
         {

               $("input[title=Title]").parent().parent().parent().hide(); 
          }  
        }
     });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Tried your approach, but for some reason Sharepoint Developer seems to the quotes and double quotes into `&quot;` and `&apos;`.

Comment: Figured out my issue. Got it to work in Chrome, but not working in IE. Any assistance with this?

Comment: Please check the detailed error using F12 Developer tool in IE.

Comment: Great... article